# A mere coincidence? $\tan5^n<0$ for all $1\leq n \leq 23, n \neq 17$

Tags: trigonometry, modular-arithmetic, exponential-function, pi

I was playing around with $\tan e^n$ and realized that $\tan5^n$ has an interesting property:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\tan 5^{1}&=&-3.380515\ldots\\
\tan 5^{2}&=&-0.133526\ldots\\
\tan 5^{3}&=&-0.782060\ldots\\
\tan 5^{4}&=&-0.178807\ldots\\
\tan 5^{5}&=&-1.221283\ldots\\
\tan 5^{6}&=&-3.364104\ldots\\
\tan 5^{7}&=&-0.126782\ldots\\
\tan 5^{8}&=&-0.729953\ldots\\
\tan 5^{9}&=&-0.011144\ldots\\
\tan 5^{10}&=&-0.055778\ldots\\
\tan 5^{11}&=&-0.286042\ldots\\
\tan 5^{12}&=&-5.565505\ldots\\
\tan 5^{13}&=&-0.811792\ldots\\
\tan 5^{14}&=&-0.274453\ldots\\
\tan 5^{15}&=&-4.242139\ldots\\
\tan 5^{16}&=&-0.438533\ldots\\
\tan 5^{17}&=&1.8498218\ldots\\
\tan 5^{18}&=&-1.278866\ldots\\
\tan 5^{19}&=&-5.604437\ldots\\
\tan 5^{20}&=&-0.821873\ldots\\
\tan 5^{21}&=&-0.307247\ldots\\
\tan 5^{22}&=&-12.42162\ldots\\
\tan 5^{23}&=&-2.354334\ldots\\
\tan 5^{24}&=&0.4677197\ldots\\
\tan 5^{25}&=&-1.410674\ldots\\
\tan 5^{26}&=&17.137346\ldots\\
\tan 5^{27}&=&3.3336581\ldots\\
\tan 5^{28}&=&0.1141382\ldots\\
\tan 5^{29}&=&0.6384773\ldots\\
\tan 5^{30}&=&-0.309809\ldots\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
It is worth noting that the first 16 $n$s and 22 $n$s out of the first 23 satisfy $\tan5^n<0$, in other words, $5^n\bmod\pi>\pi/2$.

If this is completely by chance, it seems like a little too much luck.
I have an explanation for $n=9,10,11,12$: because $5^9\bmod\pi\approx0$. But the others seems to be a coincidence, and we can say that $5^9\bmod\pi\approx0$ itself is also a coincidence. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: It would be interesting to say something about $$
f(n) = \frac{1}{{n + 1}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{\mathop{\rm sgn}} (\tan (5^k ))}  = \frac{1}{{n + 1}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{\mathop{\rm sgn}} (\sin (2 \cdot 5^k ))} .
$$ Does $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } f(n) = 0$ hold?

Comment: $\tan 5^n$ for $n=1,\ldots,100$ has $51$ negative and $49$ positive results

Comment: $\tan 5^{31} = + 3.043673534798048 \dots$